# Gradle : How to generate coverage report for Integration test using jacoco

Tags: java, gradle, jacoco

I am new to gradle. I am using the below code. But it generates coverage for unit test cases. But it didn't generate for integration test cases. I have my test classes in the package src/test/java.

```
test {
    dependsOn jettyRunWar
    ignoreFailures true
    finalizedBy jettyStop
}

apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacocoTestReport {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."
    additionalSourceDirs = files(sourceSets.main.allJava.srcDirs)
}
```

Answer (score 22):

**EDIT4**: [Gradle 7.4 RC1 release notes](https://docs.gradle.org/7.4-rc-1/release-notes.html#new-features-and-usability-improvements) indicates gradle has now the possibility to generate a single report file for both JUnit and JaCoCo. This will avoid the brittle configuration explained below.

All you have to do is apply the relevant plugins

- [`test-report-aggregation`](https://docs.gradle.org/7.4-rc-1/userguide/test_report_aggregation_plugin.html)
- [`jacoco-report-aggregation`](https://docs.gradle.org/7.4-rc-1/userguide/jacoco_report_aggregation_plugin.html)

The current downside at this moment (7.4 RC1) is that only the HTML reports are supported. And that these aggregation tasks work in concert with the [JVM test suite plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/7.4-rc-1/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html#jvm_test_suite_plugin) (yet automatically added by the `java` plugin).

So keep an eye on this feature in the next release.

Using Gradle 5.4.1 (and now 5.5.1), I was able to get a report after any test task, currently I have both `test` and `integrationTest` tasks.

**EDIT3**: Fixed a potential bug when executing only some test tasks

- Don't configure `executionData` in `doLast` / `doFirst` blocks, it was an error from my part. For more information checks this [gradle github ticket](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/11034#issuecomment-562127369)
- Added the more prudent alternative (again not in a `doLast` / `doFirst` block)
  `executionData { tasks.withType(Test).findAll { it.jacoco.destinationFile.exists() }*.jacoco.destinationFile }`

**EDIT2**: The solution is the same, I just tweaked

- the reports destination to use `jacoco.reportsDir`,
- the executionData now takes `tasks.withType(Test)` instead of just `[test, integrationTest]`
- setting `executionData` is done in the `doFirst` block instead of `doLast`

**EDIT**: After looking at the documentation of `JacocoReport`, there's a variant [JacocoReport:executionData](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport.html#org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport:executionData(org.gradle.api.Task%5B%5D)) that take Gradle tasks directly. It works because [the JaCoCo plugin adds a `JacocoTaskExtension` extension to all tasks of type `Test`](https://docs.gradle.org/5.5.1/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#sec:jacoco_specific_task_configuration). Which is then less error prone.

---

```
jacocoTestReport {
    // The JaCoCo plugin adds a JacocoTaskExtension extension to all tasks of type Test.
    // Use task state to include or not task execution data
    // https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskState.html
    // This declaration will be used as a closure, notice there no wrapping parenthesis
    executionData tasks.withType(Test).findAll { it.state.executed }
    
    // If the above instruction really don't work, there maybe some things that intervene in the process, in this case, you may be a bit more lucky with this instruction
    // executionData { tasks.withType(Test).findAll { it.jacoco.destinationFile.exists() }*.jacoco.destinationFile }

    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        xml.destination(file("${jacoco.reportsDir}/all-tests/jacocoAllTestReport.xml"))
        html.enabled true
        html.destination(file("${jacoco.reportsDir}/all-tests/html"))
    }
}
```

And the same trick can be applied to `sonarqube` task :

```
sonarqube {
    group = "verification"
    properties {
        // https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-1651
        property "sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths", jacocoTestReport.reports.xml.destination
        properties["sonar.junit.reportPaths"] += integrationTest.reports.junitXml.destination
        properties["sonar.tests"] += sourceSets.integrationTest.allSource.srcDirs
        // ... other properties
    }
}
```

---

Older but very working answer. Also using the knowledge above (that `Test`s task are extended by `JacocoTaskExtension`) it's possible to replace the manual `file` configuration of `executionData` by `test.jacoco.destinationFile` and `integrationTest.jacoco.destinationFile`.

```
// Without it, the only data is the binary data, 
// but I need the XML and HTML report after any test task
tasks.withType(Test) {
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

// Configure the report to look for executionData generated during the test and integrationTest task
jacocoTestReport {
    executionData(file("${project.buildDir}/jacoco/test.exec"),
                  file("${project.buildDir}/jacoco/integrationTest.exec"))
    reports {
        // for sonarqube
        xml.enabled true
        xml.destination(file("${project.buildDir}/reports/jacoco/all-tests/jacocoAllTestReport.xml"))
        // for devs
        html.enabled true
        html.destination file("${project.buildDir}/reports/jacoco/all-tests/html")
    }
}


sonarqube {
    group = "verification"
    properties {
        // https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-1651
        property "sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths", ${project.buildDir}/test-results/integrationTest"
        properties["sonar.junit.reportPaths"] += "${project.buildDir}/test-results/integrationTest"
        properties["sonar.tests"] += sourceSets.integrationTest.allSource.srcDirs
        // ... other properties
    }
}

project.tasks["sonarqube"].dependsOn "jacocoTestReport"
```

Comment: I tried your older solution but I ran into problems with missing ```.exec``` files. The first test step that finishes and consequently calls ```jacocoTestReport``` task assumes that all ```.exec``` files exist which is obviously not the case yet. Hence, it crashes.

Comment: yes indeed, does the newer solution solves the issues ?

Comment: @Brice
I tried your new solution, but it isn't working for me, I get the error: 
"Unable to read execution data file: C:\my-project-folder\build\test\binary"

This happens when I try to run the unit tests (gradlew test)

Comment: @NoName123 I believe I was misguided when using `doFirst`, try to use instead `executionData tasks.withType(Test).findAll { it.state.executed }` without the `doFirst`.

Comment: The newer solution worked with the alternative executionData instruction: `executionData { tasks.withType(Test).findAll { it.jacoco.destinationFile.exists() }*.jacoco.destinationFile }`

Comment: The old version works,thank you :) Just need this little fix: property "sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths", "${project.buildDir}/reports/jacoco/all-tests/jacocoAllTestReport.xml"

Answer (score 10):

I believe the most full answer will look like:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

project.jacocoTestReport {
    getExecutionData().setFrom(fileTree(buildDir).include("/jacoco/*.exec"))

    reports {
        csv.enabled true
    }
}
```

At least it's fully suited for my needs with integration and functional testing.

Answer (score 6):

Since I couldn't make it run with any of the answers, I will add my solution here.
It will work if you run your test task (e.g. `integTest`) first and call the `jacocoTestReport` afterwards.

All you need is to tell the `jacocoTestReport` task where to find the gathered execution data from you test task. The execution data is always named after the test task. So if you have a test task called `integTest`, your execution data will be stored in `build/jacoco/integTest.exec`. The `jacocoTestReport` task can be configured to look for those other files too by adding them to the property executionData. You can also add wildcards includes so all execution data is taken into consideration:

```
jacocoTestReport {
    executionData = fileTree(dir: project.projectDir, includes: ["**/*.exec"])
}
```

**UPDATE**
As stated by @rahulmohan the executionData property has become readonly. Instead define the jacocoTestReport task as below:

```
jacocoTestReport {
    getExecutionData().from(fileTree(project.projectDir).include("/jacoco/*.exec"))
```

by executing the statement below the test coverage jacoco report will be created for you integration test task (e.g. `integTest`)

```
./gradlew integTest jacocoTestReport
```

This also works for multi module projects where you want to run the `integTest` task in module `a`:

```
./gradlew a:integTest a:jacocoTestReport
```

Comment: executionData is a readonly field. I get the error: "Cannot set the value of read-only property 'executionData' for task ':jacocoTestReport' of type org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport"

Comment: Hmm, that's a bummer. For me this is working with v0.8.4 of jacoco

Answer (score 4):

It seems like, what you need to tell build.gradle is where are your Intergration tests (i.e. folder containing those IT tests) using sourceSets. In my case, i have source under src/java (instead of src/main/java - gradle default).. my unit tests (Junit) under test/java folder, and my integration tests under src/java-test folder.

```
sourceSets {
   main {
      java {
         srcDir 'src/java'
      }
   }
   test {
      java {
         srcDir 'test/java'
      }
      resources {
         srcDir 'test/resources'
         srcDir 'conf'
      }
   }
   integrationTest {
      java {
         srcDir 'src/java-test'
      }
   }
}
```

Then, I have integrationTest task as ... which you can tweak as you might not have cleanTest (custom task that i have created), so you can ignore that dependsOn... i think in your case you'll use something like jettyStart as you're using that for IT tests (starting the container for running IT tests and then finalizedBy feature to stop jetty .. jetty plugin)

```
task integrationTest( type: Test, dependsOn: cleanTest ) {
   jacoco {
      //destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec")
      destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/integrationTest.exec")
      //classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/classpathdumps")
      classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/classes/integrationTest")
   }
   testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
   classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}
```

SEE this post for more detailed output structure and script that I have at my end. Im getting the .exec for both Unit tests (test.exec) and IT tests intergrationTest.exec.. but Im not getting the jacoco.xml/jacocoHtml reports for both tests. I also found that, if I run "gradle clean build" (which includes call to "test" task) and "gradle clean build integrationTest" then, later one overwrites unit tests data in build/test-results folder and build/reports/tests folder.

[Jacoco Unit and Integration Tests coverage - individual and overall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18879250/jacoco-unit-and-integration-tests-coverage-individual-and-overall)

**NOTE**: in my case, jacocoTestReport is defined in the global gradle init.d folder in one of the common gradle file. This will help us not to include the same code in all / at project level build.gradle file.