# gradle jacoco plugin not generate exec files

Tags: gradle, jacoco

I've done gradle migration from gradle 3.5 to gradle 4.6. After migration exec files have stopped generated. '/build' folder doesn't contain 'jacoco' folder.
If I run gradle command with -- debug it writes in log :

> [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter]
>   Skipping task ':common:jacocoTestReport' as task onlyIf is false.

Here is part of gradle script:

```
subprojects {
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'idea'
...
jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        csv.enabled false
    }
    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it,
                    exclude: ['**/dto/**', '**/endpoint/**','**/enpoints/**', '**/spring/**',
                              '**/servlet/**','**/handler/**', '**/jpa/**', '**/filter/**', '**/events/**', '**/dao/**',
                              '**/exception/**', '**/http/**', '**/jdbc/**', '**/bigquery/**', '**/enums/**',
                              '**/repository/**', '**/combination/**', '**/datastore/**', '**/cassandra/**',
                              '**/google/**', '**/exceptions/**', '**/logging/**', '**/JavaGeneratedContext.java', '**/Q*.java'])
        })
    }
}

test {
    enabled = !skipTests
    allJvmArgs = [
        '-Dfile.encoding=utf-8'
    ]
    useJUnit {
        excludeCategories 'com.severn.common.test.IntegrationTest'
    }
    /*jacoco {
        enabled = true
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec")
    }*/
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

...

}
```

Comment: What is the gradle command line you are using ?

Comment: gradle clean build

Comment: Hunar, can you share the detailed (`--debug`) output for the `test` task. Is that running or not. Otherwise for the `test`s to run. This error is simply because you don't have .exec file `destinationFile` variable location and jacocoTestReport is looking for that, thus the error.

Comment: Also look into the latest Gradle version's distro (full zip/tar) to see examples of `Jacoco` in a Java project, see if something has changed that you may need to include now for creating the .exec file(s)

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure**:

1) Your debug info is enabled during compile in your top level Gradle file (`allprojects { ... }` ). See here for more info: [Jacoco Unit and Integration Tests coverage - individual and overall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18879250/jacoco-unit-and-integration-tests-coverage-individual-and-overall)

```
   tasks.withType(Compile) {
     options.debug = true
     options.compilerArgs = ["-g"]
   }
```

2) Try removing the whole Jacoco configuration from the `test` task (make sure you place the .exec file if generated in the default location where jacocoTestReport task expects it). Make sure `test` task is running (and not getting excluded somehow). For testing purpose (to narrow down this .exec not getting created issue), you can force `jacocoTestReport` task to dependOn `test` task.

```
tasks.withType(Test) {enabled = true}
```

3) See latest Gradle 4.6 bundle (tar/zip) for Jacoco examples for a Java single/multi level project to get hint.

**PS:** Default JaCoCo version upgraded to **0.8.0** See if forcing this version within `jacoco` block helps.

https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html
The JaCoCo plugin has been upgraded to use JaCoCo version 0.8.0 by default.